# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \wp-includes\functions.php:4986) in \wp-includes\pluggable.php

Tags: wordpress

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \wp-includes\functions.php:4986) in \wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1265`

В ошибке указываются два файла ядра `wordpress`, получается ошибка в ядре?

Comment: Даже не надейтесь ))) Ошибка говорит о том, что невозможно послать заголовки - вывод уже начат в functions.php:4986. А там явно вылезло сообщение об ошибке, вызванное плагинами/темой.

Comment: строка 4986 - это сообщение о том, что что-то было вызвано неправильно "'%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>" - смотрите логи